# How to get current focus view object in Service?

Tags: android, service, focus

How can i get the current focus view in my Service.

I found some methods to do this, like Activity.getCurrentFocus() and
Windows.getCurrentFocus().
But these methods are used in a Activity.

If I want to use these, I have to get the current focus activity.
I tried to use WindowManager to get current task.
It only got the current Activity's class name in this way. not
Activity Object.

```
   List<RunningAppProcessInfo> rList =activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            RunningTaskInfo rt = rtList.get(0);
      rt.topActivity.getClassName(); // the class name of the current Activity
```

How can I use these methods to get the current focus View in a
Service? Or is there another way to
do?

Answer (score 0):

A service is a background work, so is not tied to any UI.
What you can do is bind your service to an Activity and call some method (through an interface) on this activity to return the focused view of this activity.

Anyway, can you explain better what you want to achieve? normally a Service don't apply to do things with UI, so maybe there is a better way to do what you want.